# how to create a datamodel in ios for array of itself dynamically using swift?

Tags: swift4

How to create a data model for below given example so that i can dynamically develop this array of any size?
my data will be like

```
let dataArray = [[
            self.keyIndent: 0, self.keyTitle: "title 0", self.keyChildren: [[
                self.keyIndent: 1, self.keyTitle: "title 01", self.keyChildren: [[
                    self.keyIndent: 2, self.keyTitle: "title 011", self.keyChildren: [[
                        self.keyIndent: 3, self.keyTitle: "title 0111", self.keyChildren: [[
                            self.keyIndent: 4, self.keyTitle: "title 01111", self.keyChildren: []],  [self.keyIndent: 4, self.keyTitle: "title 01112", self.keyChildren: []]]]]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but I'd *design* the model class like this:

```
class MyModel
{
    var title: String?
    var children: [MyModel]?

    func buildDataModel(input: [MyModel]) -> [[String:Any]]?
    {
         // Dynamically build your array here, by walking input and its descendents.
         // keep track of the indent as you progress, so you can insert it to each dictionary as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: i am trying to implement a tableview which expands and contracts based on above array data..

Comment: So I gave you the model class.  You should first write the buildDataModel method, which takes your deserialized JSON (your dataArray) and creates a MyModel (which has MyModel children and descendents).  Then have your tableView delegate methods use your MyModel to figure out each row's data.  I don't know how you want to represent this as a single table, as nested tables, or what.  But you should be on your way now.  This question was just about what data model you should use.  Please ask a separate detailed question if you get stuck again as you develop your app.

Comment: **@I don't know how you want to represent this as a single table, as nested tables, or what.:- **               i was using this https://github.com/deepakbforhati99/multiLevelUITableView for implementing the above data model..